# How to create a log using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to do some Rails development and I would like to log all the output from the console to a text file that I can access once done. How can I do this and then access the text file in Windows?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for either `my_command > text_file.txt` or `my_command | tee text_file.txt`, that's assuming that there is some `my_command` that you run that you want to capture output from...

Comment: Does the `script` command exist on windows?

Comment: Ideally I would like to just log any output. So when I start my rails server in Bash, log all the output to a file that I can access from Windows. So this isn't a single script I'm running.